how to send transaction from dedust sdk via tonconnect?
I get data for exchange from dedust sdk (ton > jetton )
import { toNano } from '@ton/core';

// ...

const amountIn = toNano('5'); // 5 TON

await tonVault.sendSwap(sender, {
  poolAddress: pool.address,
  amount: amountIn,
  gasAmount: toNano("0.25"),
});

how can i transfer them to the client and send the transaction via tonconnect/ui?
tonConnectUI.sendTransaction({...})

now i send transaction to stonfi this way:
const txParams = await router.getSwapTonToJettonTxParams({
            userWalletAddress: user.ton_wallet,
            proxyTon: new pTON.v1(),
            offerAmount: toNano("0.1"),
            askJettonAddress: token.ca,
            minAskAmount: min_ask,
            queryId: 123,
        });

        const tx = {
            address: txParams.to.toString(),
            amount: txParams.value.toString(),
            payload: txParams.body?.toBoc().toString("base64"),
        }

